# Access variable from event handler in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, event-handling

I'm trying to create a jQuery class to validate input fields when a form is submitted. I have different forms into the same page and I need to create a validator instance for each form.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="form1">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="index.php" id="form2">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var form1 = new DataValidator('#form1');
var form2 = new DataValidator('#form2');
</script>
```

I would access object variables from submit event handler, but when I print `this.selector` variable, I see an `undefined` value.

**JavaScript**

```
function DataValidator(selector)
{
  this.form = $(selector);
  this.selector = selector;

  $(selector).submit(function() 
  {
    alert('submit ' + this.selector);
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: [Recommended read: `this` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is not a local variable, so it doesn't get saved in closures. You need to save it in a local variable. In jQuery event handlers, `this` is always bound to the target of the event.

```
function DataValidator(selector)
{
  this.form = $(selector);
  this.selector = selector;
  var self = this;

  this.form.submit(function() 
  {
    alert('submit ' + self.selector);
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: in fact `this` in the OP's code is just the `form` object, not the object created by `DataValidator` constructor.